# Calculo de tabla con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo una tabla la cuál me sirve para agregar productos a una venta:

```
     <table class="table" id="tablaDetalle">
            {{ detalleformset.management_form }}
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <th>Producto</th>
                <th width="100px">Cantidad</th>
                <th width="115px">Prec.Unit.</th>
                <th width="115px">Subtotal</th>
                <th>Acción</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for form in detalleformset.forms %}
                <tr class="formset_row">
                    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
                        <td>
                            {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
                            {% if forloop.first %}
                                {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
                                    {{ hidden }}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endif %}
                            {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
                            {{ field }}
                        </td>
                    {% endfor %}
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Esto no tiene mucho que ver ya que esto lo hace **django** perefectamente ya que actualmente estoy usando este para tal proyecto.

y este es mi **jquery:**

```
   $('.formset_row').formset({
        addText: 'Agregar Producto',
        deleteText: 'remover',
        prefix: 'detalleventa'
    });
    $(function() {    
        $("#tablaDetalle").on("change", "input", function(){
          var row = $(this).closest("tr");
          var cantidad = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(2)").val());
          var precio = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(3)").val());
          var subtotal = parseInt(cantidad, 10) * parseFloat(precio);
          row.find("input:eq(4)").val(isNaN(subtotal) ? "" : subtotal.toFixed(2));

          var total = 0;
            $(".subtotal").each(function () {
                var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
                total += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
            });
            $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));

            $('.delete-row').click(function(){
                var $fila = $(this).parents('tr');
                var valsub = parseFloat($fila.find('input:eq(4)').val());
                new Promise(function(done){
                    total -= isNaN(valsub) ? 0 : valsub;
                    $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));
                    done();
                })
                .then(function(){
                    var id0 = parseFloat($fila.find('#id_detalleventa-0-subtotal').val(0));
                })
            });
        });  
      });
</script>
```

En el cuál mi problema surje al querer editar una venta... porque? porque cuando yo registro hago cambios en los  campos(input) por ejemplo el input **cantidad** y cuando hace ese cambio recién calcula y me funciona hasta el remover ese elemento de la tabla todo perfecto! pero cuando voy a editar una venta y le doy remover a ese elemento... el total no cambia ya que no hay cambios en los input... simplemente estoy removiendo un elemento. Hay otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: ¿Por qué tienes el controlador de evento que controla el borrado dentro del evento que controla el cambio en el `input`? De ese modo no se borrará hasta que no se haga un cambio en el input. Simplemente sácalo y ya debería funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás asociando el controlador del borrado dentro del controlador del cambio en un `input`, entonces el borrado sólo funcionará después de hacer un cambio en un `input` y no antes (el comportamiento que describes).

La solución sería mover la asociación del evento para `.delete-row` fuera del controlador del cambio en `input` (fuera del `$("#tablaDetalle").on("change", "input", function(){`) y creo que también tienes que hacerlo de manera delegada (para evitar problemas si el botón se añade de forma dinámica).

Algo como esto (lee los comentarios para detalles):

```
$(function() {    
    $("#tablaDetalle").on("change", "input", function(){
      var row = $(this).closest("tr");
      var cantidad = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(2)").val());
      var precio = parseFloat(row.find("input:eq(3)").val());
      var subtotal = parseInt(cantidad, 10) * parseFloat(precio);
      row.find("input:eq(4)").val(isNaN(subtotal) ? "" : subtotal.toFixed(2));

      var total = 0;
        $(".subtotal").each(function () {
            var stval = parseFloat($(this).val());
            total += isNaN(stval) ? 0 : stval;
        });
        $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));
    });  

    // mueve el código del .delete-row fuera del controlador del input
    // y hazlo delegado (esto creo que es necesario, aunque no estoy seguro)
    $("#tablaDetalle").on("click", '.delete-row', function(){
        // aquí tendrás que volver a leer los valores de las variables usadas (p.e. total)
        var total = $('.total').val();
        var $fila = $(this).parents('tr');
        var valsub = parseFloat($fila.find('input:eq(4)').val());
        new Promise(function(done){
            total -= isNaN(valsub) ? 0 : valsub;
            $('.total').val(total.toFixed(2));
            done();
        })
        .then(function(){
            var id0 = parseFloat($fila.find('#id_detalleventa-0-subtotal').val(0));
        })
    });
});
```

Comment: Si habia probado de esa manera pero cuando lo pongo afuera no me lo resta y no me refresca el total y puse la variable total fuera de la función de los cambios del input para que sea global y cuando le doy remover el campo lo resta pero doble vez o sea si era 4.50 el valor de ese campo lo resta 2 veces  dando asi un -4.50 igual muchas gracias Alvaro !

Comment: @PieroPajaresOrihuela actualicé la respuesta. Si no te funcione, crea un [mcve] para que podamos ver el problema,